# Flutter listen Bloc state from Other Bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Hello I'm trying to listen state of bloc from other bloc.
I'm using this package https://pub.dev/packages/bloc

From my **UserBloc** I want listen **AuthBloc** and when It has the state **AuthenticationAuthenticated** the **UserBloc** should fire an event.

```
final UserRepository userRepository;
final authBloc;
StreamSubscription authSub;
UserBloc({ @required this.userRepository, @required this.authBloc}) {
    authSub = authBloc.listen((stateAuth) {

      //here is my problem because stateAuth, even is AuthenticationAuthenticated it return always false.
      if (stateAuth is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
        this.add(GetUser())  ;
      }
    });
  }

@override
  Future<void> close() async {
    authSub?.cancel();
    super.close();
  }
```

For now I have this problem:
When in debug I'm trying to print stateAuth it return:

```
stateAuth = {AuthenticationAuthenticated} AuthenticationAuthenticated
   props = {_ImmutableList} size = 0
```

But **stateAuth is AuthenticationAuthenticated** return always false.

Is there any way for listen blocState From Other Bloc class?

Comment: Did you manage to do this, I'm trying to accomplish something similar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To answer Sampir's question, yes, you're right, but sometimes you may want to do it in another way.
A bloc is something that manages an event for someone else. If you are working with ui events, your bloc manages them for your ui, but if you are working also with other kind of events (i.e. position events, or other streams events) you can have a bloc that manages your ui events and antoher bloc that manages the other kind of events (i.e. a bluetooth connection). So the first bloc must listen to the second one (i.e. because is waiting for establishing bluetooth connection). Think about an app that uses a lot of sensors, each one with its stream of data, and you'll have a chain of blocs that have to cooperate. 
You can do it with multi-provider and multi-listener but your chain could be very long and writing your listener cases can be hard, or you may want to hide it from your ui, or you want to reuse it in another part of your app, so you may want to build your chain inside your blocs.

You can add a listener to a bloc almost everywhere. Using StreamSubscription, you can add a listener to every kind of streams, even the one in another bloc. The bloc must have a method to expose his stream, so you can listen to him.

Some code (I use flutter_bloc - flutter_bloc has multi-providers, but it's just for example):

```
class BlocA extends Bloc<EventA, StateA> {

  final BlocB blocB;
  StreamSubscription subscription;

  BlocA({this.blocB}) {
    if (blocB == null) return;
    subscription = blocB.listen((stateB) {
      //here logic based on different children of StateB
    });
  }

  //...

}

class BlocB extends Bloc<EventB, StateB> {
   //here BlocB logic and activities
}
```

Comment: I have question i'm doing same what u mention about Bluetooth connection but for WiFi and cellular i'm using block i want this block to listen for change happen to connectivity and rebuild the UI but in this way i had only one block use the connection class , but to trigger build i had to use event from UI. what i want to do is to trigger the event from background thread that watch connection change.

Comment: Please note that listening to other blocs inside of a bloc is discouraged, because it creates tight coupling between them. You can avoid it by wrapping the BlocProvider of BlocA with a BlocListener for BlocB and adding events to BlocA for every event of BlocB. See https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication

Comment: Probably the right answer now is from this comment bellow https://stackoverflow.com/a/72496719/4943676

Answer (score 21):

Actually in one of the [examples](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_todos) of the [bloc library](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) they listen to a Bloc (TodosBloc) from another Bloc (FilteredTodosBloc).

```
class FilteredTodosBloc extends Bloc<FilteredTodosEvent, FilteredTodosState> {
  final TodosBloc todosBloc;
  StreamSubscription todosSubscription;

  FilteredTodosBloc({@required this.todosBloc}) {
    todosSubscription = todosBloc.listen((state) {
      if (state is TodosLoadSuccess) {
        add(TodosUpdated((todosBloc.state as TodosLoadSuccess).todos));
      }
    });
  }
...
```

You can check this example's explanation [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-todos-tutorial-with-flutter-bloc-d9dd833f9df3).

Comment: The article is marked as out of date, the latest doesn't use this approach anymore, don't know if it is still appropriate.

Comment: To add to the comment above, probably the right answer now is from this comment bellow https://stackoverflow.com/a/72496719/4943676

Answer (score 14):

You might not want your bloc to depend on another bloc with direct bloc-to-bloc dependency, instead, you might want to connect your bloc through the presentation layer.

You can use a BlocListener to listen to one bloc and add an event to another bloc whenever the first bloc changes.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<WeatherCubit, WeatherState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // When the first bloc's state changes, this will be called.
        //
        // Now we can add an event to the second bloc without it having
        // to know about the first bloc.
        BlocProvider.of<SecondBloc>(context).add(SecondBlocEvent());
      },
      child: TextButton(
        child: const Text('Hello'),
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<FirstBloc>(context).add(FirstBlocEvent());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code above prevents SecondBloc from needing to know about FirstBloc, encouraging loose-coupling.

Check the official [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication) for more info.

Comment: this should be correct answer, others are outdated.

Comment: the correct answer below from @Vingtoft

Comment: The 'best practice' approach of putting the business logic in the presentation layer is dire IMO. This new answer is much better https://stackoverflow.com/a/76900070/1058292. Business logic should be separated so we can test how our components interact without depending on all the messy front end code. The linked solution also means that BlockA doesn't depend on the entirety of BlockB when it only needs a little bit of it.  This helps mocking and testing.  listeners in the front end code should be reserved for front end work such as hiding and showing snackbars.

Answer (score 8):

A recent update in the bloc source code requires a small change to the solution.

You now have to listen to a bloc/cubit's stream attribute, please see below example.

```
class FilteredTodosBloc extends Bloc<FilteredTodosEvent, FilteredTodosState> {
  final TodosBloc todosBloc;
  StreamSubscription todosSubscription;

  FilteredTodosBloc({@required this.todosBloc}) {
    todosSubscription = todosBloc.stream.listen((state) {
    //                             ^^^^^
      if (state is TodosLoadSuccess) {
        add(TodosUpdated((todosBloc.state as TodosLoadSuccess).todos));
      }
    });
  }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers that suggest passing a bloc to another bloc are not that great imo, as they will create tight coupling between the 2 blocs.

I think the answers that suggest passing the state of the first bloc to the dependent bloc are better, and they can be imporved by this approach below where you really decouple the blocs from each other using a stream of custom class/record that will be passed to the dependent bloc, this way you can decouple the blocs and also listen only to the part of the first bloc's state that you are interested in, in the second bloc:

```
class PartialState{ // partial state of bloc B that bloc A is interested in (it can be also the whole state, in which case you pass below the state stream directly instead of a stream of this class)
  final SomeParamFromBlocBState param1;

  final AnotherParamFromBlocBState? param2;

  // constructor...
}

class BlocA extends Bloc<EventA, StateA> {

  final PartialState partialState;
  StreamSubscription<PartialState> subscription;

  BlocA(Stream<PartialState> stream) {
    subscription = stream.listen((partialState) {
      // do something
    });
  }

//...

}

class BlocB extends Bloc<EventB, StateB> {
  //here BlocB logic and activities
}

// somewhere in your app
void main(){
  final blocB = BlocB();
  final blocA = BlocA(blocB.state.map((state) => PartialState(param1: state.param1, param2: state.param2)));
}
```

notes:

- Don't forget to close the subscription in the bloc's `close` method.
- Be careful when listening to the state of a bloc from another bloc, because if you are defining your blocs in some build method and the bloc that is providing the stream rebuilds while the depending bloc doesn't build, the depending bloc may have broken state as the stream it is listening to is no longer valid.
- Using `BlocListener` is also ok sometimes,other times its not, example: say you want to listen to some state of `BlocB` and call `onBlocBChanged` method defined in `BlocA`, if you are going to do this once in your widgets, then its ok, but if you need to call this  in many places, you may forget to call it somewhere (i.e. you may forget to put a bloc listener), in this case a better approach is to centralize the call by using the above approach.

### Update 1

I also want to mention that injecting the dependency (i.e. a stream or record or etc...) to the dependent bloc throught the constructor makes unit-testing this bloc easy, opposed to the other solutions where you make the bloc dependent on another bloc, because in that case in your unit test you will need to create the two blocs only to unit-test one bloc.

Comment: The 'best practice' approach of putting the business logic in the presentation layer is dire IMO.  This is much better.  Business logic should be separated so we can test how our components interact without depending on all the messy front end code.  This solution also means that BlockA doesn't depend on the entirety of BlockB when it only needs a little bit of it.

Comment: @atreeon exactly, this solution is perfect if someone wants to unit-test his bloc, I will edit the answer to also mention this important point which is only available because of the decoupling proposed by this solution

Comment: The state doesn't have `map` method.How to solve it?

Comment: @Terriermon you can either implement the `map` yourself, or use some library as `Freezed`

Comment: @Terriermon I wrote https://pub.dev/packages/morphy which allows polymorphic copywith and polymorphic json serialization.  Would this help?

Comment: Can you clarify some of the gotchas you mentioned about build methods etc please?

Comment: @Sam if blocB depends on a stream from blocA, and for some reason blocA is recreated, then blocB must either be recreated to update its dependency on blocA, or blocB should be notified that blocA has been recreated. If you forget to do one of these 2 options, then blocB might be considered in a "broken" state where it holds reference to a stream that is out of date. It might or might not cause an exception, but most probably it will cause business error in your code.