# Flutter BLoC listening to other blocs

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc

I am fairly new to Flutter and very new to using BLoc.

I have a situation where I need to have a single BLoc respond to state changes in two other BLoc's.

The BLoC's are set up as follows:

```
    body: MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => NeighborBloc(repository: pcRepository),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => FamilyBloc(repository: pcRepository),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => RegionBloc(
              repository: repository,
              neighborBloc: BlocProvider.of<NeighborBloc>(context),
              familyBloc: BlocProvider.of<FamilyBloc>(context)),
        ),
      ],
```

The constructor for RegionBloc is:

```
RegionBloc(
   {@required this.neighborBloc,
   @required this.familyBloc,
   @required this.repository})
   : assert(repository != null),
     super(RegionEmpty()) {
 print("NB: " + neighborBloc .toString());
 print("FB: " + familyBloc .toString());
 _neighborBlocSubscription = neighborBloc.listen((neighborState) {
   if (neighborState is NeighborSelected) {
     Postcode postcode = (neighborState as NeighborSelected).postcode;
     add(NeighborSelected(postcode));
   }
 });
 _familyBlocSubscription = familyBloc.listen((familyState) {
   if (familyState is FamilySelected) {
     Postcode postcode = (familyState as FamilySelected).postcode;
     add(FamilySelected(postcode));
   }
 });
}
```

The result of the two print statements are:
NB: Instance of 'NeighborBloc'
FB: Instance of 'FamilyBloc'

I have a BlocObserver setup and I get the transitions for the neighborState

```
onTransition  NeighborBloc, transition: Transition { currentState: NeighborLoading, event: 
SelectNeighbor, nextState: NeighborSelected }
onChange NeighborBloc, Change { currentState: NeighborLoading, nextState:      
    NeighborSelected }
```

The RegionBloc->NeighborSelection is never added.  The BlocBuilder for
the RegionBloc is:

```
return BlocBuilder<RegionBloc, RegionState>(builder: (context, state) {
  if (state is RegionEmpty) {
    return Text('Empty Region');
  }
  if (state is RegionLoaded) {
    return Text('RegionsLoaded');
  }
  if (state is NeighborSelected) {
    return Text('NeighborSelected');
  }
  if (state is FamilySelected) {
    return Text('FamilySelected');
  }
  //return Center(
  //  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  //);
  setPolygon();
  return Container(
```

I have read this link and I think I am doing it:
[Flutter listen Bloc state from Other Bloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137180/flutter-listen-bloc-state-from-other-bloc)

I can't tell what I am not doing or doing wrong.

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I never get the Region->NeighborSelected event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BlocBuilder<RegionBloc, RegionState>` will only react to `RegionState`.

You need to create a `BlocBuilder<NeighborBloc, NeighborState>` to react to `NeighborSelected`

Comment: I copied the print from the RegionBloc where it looks at the two bloc's to be sure they aren't null and they are the instances of the classes.  I edited the question to add this info.

Comment: Do you create those bloc somewhere else before ? IMO, the instances you get are not those you creates above, so you may get a wrong behavior

Comment: They are not created any other place.  I will look to see if when a dart instance is created, if there is a unique identifier and see if I can use it to tell what you claim.   I am working to figure out how to create them else where and pass them in.

Comment: I print out the hashCode for the two bloc's in the regionBloc constructor and on each of the two bloc constructors and they are the same.

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong and both `BlocProvider.of<NeighborBloc>(context)` and `BlocProvider.of<FamilyBloc>(context)` references the instances above.
Providers just need to be created in order.

Comment: I have understand you problem and edited the answer ;)

Comment: Unfortunately there is an instance of NeighborBloc in a different widget that responds to the NeighborSelect event in the NeighborEvent class.  There was a name collision, im not that fond of dart, in the name of the event that the RegionBloc was adding and I think it confused the bloc subsystem.  When the event name added by RegionBloc -> NeighborSelected is changed to RegionNeighborSelected the event is actually added.

Comment: RegionBloc can only add RegionEvent instances.

Comment: Do the `NeighborSelected` is part of `RegionBloc` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224265/discussion-between-f-perroch-and-nefarious).