# flutter_bloc 8: what is the best practice for listening to state changes from another bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

What is the best practice for listening to another bloc’s state changes?

This answer was relevant in previous version, but it doesn’t work in version 8 (`.listen` method doesn’t exist anymore on a bloc): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62785980/160919

```
FilteredTodosBloc({@required this.todosBloc}) {
  todosSubscription = todosBloc.listen((state) {
    if (state is TodosLoadSuccess) {
      add(TodosUpdated((todosBloc.state as TodosLoadSuccess).todos));
    }
});}
```

What is the recommended approach to listen to a state change from another bloc in flutter_bloc 8?

Comment: Check this out: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication

Comment: If you're still looking for the recommended method of listening to a bloc from another bloc, don't hesitate to check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72496719/12649675 .

The answer is based on the link from @PeterObiechina comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

State stream is now exposed via `stream` getter, so you can still use almost the same code:

```dart
FilteredTodosBloc({required this.todosBloc}) {
  todosSubscription = todosBloc.stream.listen((state) {
    if (state is TodosLoadSuccess) {
      add(TodosUpdated((todosBloc.state as TodosLoadSuccess).todos));
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really changed in terms of recommended approach. All you have to do is call `stream` property first and listen to it intead of bloc directly. So if you previously listened to blocs / cubits like this:
`myBloc.listen((state) => print(state));`

all you need to change is call `stream` first, like this:

`myBloc.stream.listen((state) => print(state));`